# Magento Currency Symbol 404's when i go to admin

Tags: magento, admin, currency

Any ideas what would cause:

admin->system->manage currency->symbols

to 404 when i go to it in the admin?

admin->system->manage currency->rates (works fine).

This is on my mamp local.

i guess i'm asking is there a 'troubleshooting' way to find out why it's 404'ing for any module in the admin?

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem - though I do not know whether it is caused by any extensions. Somehow not many people seem to have encountered this problem yet.

Change line 68 in `app\code\core\Mage\CurrencySymbol\etc\config.xml`:  and

change From

```
<currencysymbol>Mage_CurrencySymbol_Adminhtml</currencysymbol>
```

to

```
<currencysymbol before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mage_CurrencySymbol_Adminhtml</currencysymbol>
```

Comment: I couldn't replicate it on the live environment but ill try your idea on my local when I'm next get a chance.

Comment: Works! Magento 1.7.0.2. Problem happens on stock magento without any extensions. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Go to line 68 in app/code/core/Mage/CurrencySymbol/etc/config.xml

```
<currencysymbol>Mage_CurrencySymbol_Adminhtml</currencysymbol>
```

Replace to

```
<currencysymbol before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mage_CurrencySymbol_Adminhtml</currencysymbol>
```

Go to line 34 in app/etc/modules/Mage_CurrencySymbol.xml add the Mage_Adminhtml tag

```
<depends>
 <Mage_Adminhtml />
 <Mage_Widget/>
</depends>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs with the definition of the admin router. It appears not only to be a windows error as I am also getting this on a linux machine. Currently it looks as follows:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <currencysymbol>Mage_CurrencySymbol_Adminhtml</currencysymbol>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

But if you use the "before" tag and specify "Mage_Adminhtml" then it will work.

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <currencysymbol before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mage_CurrencySymbol_Adminhtml</currencysymbol>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

You should also add the dependency to the /app/etc/modules/Mage_CurrencySymbol.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_CurrencySymbol>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>core</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Adminhtml />
                <Mage_Widget/>
            </depends>
        </Mage_CurrencySymbol>
    </modules>
</config>
```

There appears to have been a bug/fix raised on [github](https://github.com/magento/bugathon_march_2013/commit/41bffaef075de3e7ffee2d9354fb8ffe098f6b4d)

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/code/core/Mage/CurrencySymbol/etc/config.xml

```
<args>



    <modules>


        <currencysymbol>Mage_CurrencySymbol_Adminhtml</currencysymbol>


        <currencysymbol after="Mage_Adminhtml">Mage_CurrencySymbol_Adminhtml</currencysymbol> // Add this new line


    </modules>


</args>
```

Now go to app/etc/modules/Mage_CurrencySymbol.xml

true

core

```
<depends>


    <Mage_Adminhtml />  // Add this new line


    <Mage_Widget/>


</depends>
```